# How to add extra parameter in drupal core search?

Tags: search

Please check the image attached
[image: screenshot]

How should I append this second field value with some conditions to core search?

Comment: You can use hook_form_alter function where you can check form_id and then add your extra field. Also write your custom callback for submit search keyword

Comment: Or if you want to apply this filter on content list in admin panel. you can check  https://drupal.org/project/admin_views module

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided. See [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: By the way, aren't you by accident a team-mate of a guy who asked [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/107650/16495)?

Comment: No i dont have any idea about this person.

Comment: @Yogesh Yes, you do. I suspect it's a duplicate account of your own, but just in case it isn't, and is a colleague working from the same location, please coordinate with each other in future so you don't post duplicate questions.